# How to validate multiple XSD Schemas with Spring's PayloadValidatingInterceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, xsd, wsdl, spring-ws

I have a Spring Boot project with multiple XSD Schemas (I'm using Spring-WS).

If I use Spring's PayloadValidatingInterceptor to validate requests and responses, it only works with the latest set schema.

For instance:

```
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(getFirstSchema());
    validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(getSecondSchema());
    interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
    super.addInterceptors(interceptors);
}
```

This snippet will make Spring to validate only the second schema, not the first. I've tried creating multiple PayloadValidatingInterceptors to add them with super.addInterceptors(interceptors);, but it didn't work either. The only response I was able to find (with Java instead of XML), is from 2009:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-481

Does anyone know of a Java-based solution to validate requests and responses from multiple XSDs in the same project?

Comment: Have you tried using setXsdSchemaCollection instead of setXsdSchema?  If yes, then what went wrong?  If no, then why not?

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work. I wasn't able to find a sample for an implementation using setXsdSchema either. The method asks you to implement XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() and XmlValidator createValidator(), but I have no idea how to implement the createValidator() method. Simply returning null makes the application unusable, and XmlValidtor can't be instanciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting a solution for future reference, since I wasn't able to find a single example in internet.

To validate multiple schemas, this is what I did:

Instead of validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(), I ended up using validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchemaCollection().

This receives an XsdSchemaCollection, which you need to instanciate and implement 2 anon methods, like this:

```
    XsdSchemaCollection schemaCollection = new XsdSchemaCollection() {

        @Override
        public XsdSchema[] getXsdSchemas() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public XmlValidator createValidator() {
            try {
                XmlValidator xmlValidator = XmlValidatorFactory.createValidator(getSchemas(), "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

                return xmlValidator;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

The getSchemas() method returns an array of Resources from where you pass the current XSDs to validate:

```
public Resource[] getSchemas() {
    List<Resource> schemaResources = new ArrayList<>();
    schemaResources.add(new ClassPathResource("firstService.xsd"));
    schemaResources.add(new ClassPathResource("secondService.xsd"));
    schemaResources.add(new ClassPathResource("thirdService.xsd"));
    return schemaResources.toArray(new Resource[schemaResources.size()]);
}
```

Comment: in this case all 3 schems are belog to one request? any idea how to do for multiple requests

Answer (score 0):

If you centralize all the xsd's in 1 file(import all xsd's in 1 file) you can use schemaCollection:

```
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);

//use setXsdSchemaCollection instead of setXsdSchema
validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchemaCollection(getFirstSchema());

interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
super.addInterceptors(interceptors);
```

}